# Обновление данных в MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть данные в иерархическом виде- индексы файлов и папок. Нужно создать хранимую процедуру для обновления. То есть, просматриваем ФС на предмет изменений. Есть файл- проверить, что он есть и в базе. Если отсутствует в базе, но есть в ФС - добавить в базу. Если есть в БД, но отсутствует в ФС- удалить соответствующую запись из БД.
Мне сказали, что эту процедуру лучше реализовать с помошью триггеров. Действительно ли лучше?
Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией- то отправьте на нужный ресурс, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По опыту работы могу посоветовать на выбор пару технологий автоматизации.

1. Использовать SSIS. Достаточно легко работать с ФС, ещё легче с БД. Но возможно, чтобы докрутить нужный функционал, придется использовать сторонние разработки, которые позволяют следить за изменениями в ФС. Например: [SQLIS File Watcher Task](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/File-Watcher-Task.aspx).
2. Написать небольшую утилитку (а может даже windows-сервис), который будет следить за изменениями ФС. Делается это с помощью подписывания на события файловой системы с помощью: [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Если же вы хотите реализовать всё только с помощью MSSQL, то вам может помочь SQL Agent, который будет запускать задачу по расписанию. А в задачу вы можете впихнуть, например, хранимую процедуру. У SQL Server есть недокументированные функции: **xp_subdirs** и **xp_dirtree**.

Используйте первую, чтобы получить список всех поддиректорий указанной директории, например, так:

```
EXEC master..xp_subdirs 'C:\\'
```

Используйте вторую, чтобы получить список всех директории рекурсивно, а также глубину вложенности.

```
EXEC master..xp_dirtree 'C:\\'
```

Чтобы получить список файлов в папке, уже придется обращаться с командной строке с помощью другой функции **xp_cmdshell**:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR /b C:\'
```

Проверка на наличие файла в ФС:

```
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'C:\boot.ini'
```

Вот, пожалуйста, ещё материалы для размышления, вариант - только T-SQL:

- [Stored procedures to retrieve directory listing – Undocumented XPs](http://sqlandme.com/2011/05/12/stored-procedures-to-retrieve-directory-listing-undocumented-xps/)
- [List Directories and Files using T-SQL](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1002&lngWId=5)
- [Get list of files in directory using a SP](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143311-get-list-files-directory-using-sp)

Comment: У меня уже разработана утилитка по считыванию ФС и формированию БД иерархической структуры. И функционал отслеживания изменений в ФС реализован.
Мне бы хотелось узнать, возможно ли создать хранимую процедуру, которая будет включать 2 подхода к БД: Первый - добавление новых данных в бд с проверкой, есть ли такая запись. Проверку буду осуществлять по пути к файлу. ну или по ветке и имени. (те есть, считываем файл-формируем запись, если есть запись- все отлично).
Второй - проверка существования файла. Есть файл в соответствии с записью- все отлично. Нету- удаляем запись и все её подуровни.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что для этой реализации минимум 2 процедуры нужно.
И еще бы мне хотелось узнать, как средствами sql проверить существование файла, имея к нему путь.

Comment: Используйте EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist Filename , чтобы проверить существование файла.
Чтобы дать действительно дельный совет надо понимать, что у вас за хранилище сейчас, как оно устроено. Может быть проще сделать отдельное место, куда закидываются файлы, а потом они загоняются в БД? Это было бы проще в плане проверки на новые файлы и уменьшить количество итераций при проверке на удаленные.

Comment: Спасибо за exec master!
да, у меня сервере будет специальная папка, в которую будут данные скидываться. А на изменения в ней будет реагировать приложение.

Comment: @Tyler, ещё вопросы остались? Я ничего не упустил?

Comment: Да нет, вроде. В голове уже нарисовалось представление. Спасибо!